# What options are there for registering a domain for URL forwarding and nothing else?

Tags: url, forwarding, domain-registration

I would like to register a domain so that I own it and it redirects to my website - nothing more fancy than that.  So far in my research I haven't found any service that does only that.  There have always been extra features I have to pay for that are very nice, but unfortunately I won't be using them.

Is there such a thing as a service that allows you to register a domain so that you own it and redirect all URLs without paying for anything else?

Comment: What extras are you referring to?

Comment: Any options related to hosting, email, DNS technical options, etc.  I don't need anything other than the most basic DNS and a forward.

Comment: Why can't you just setup a wildcard address in the DNS zone, and set it to point at your existing web server?  Then setup virtual hosts or whatever on your web server.

Comment: Oh, and FYI: http://www.dyndns.com/services/webredirect/

Comment: @jnm2: OK, but you understand that you don't have to select any extras right?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Well, I've yet to find a package that simply registers and redirects without any kind of hosting or other features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain registration and hosting are separate things, most companies sell domains separate from hosting. So you first have to buy the domain. A lot of companies will charge you extra for domain forwarding but some won't so look or ask whether they charge extra. As far as I know godaddy(dot)com doesn't charge for forwarding and have decent prices but you might find something cheaper.

Comment: That's the thing - I don't want hosting.  I just want it to redirect to my other website.

Comment: That's what I said then just buy a domain. Like in my post if you go to http://www.godaddy.com/domains/search.aspx?isc=dsc7&ci=8990 you can see their prices for domains and the only extra services you get pertains to making it easier to manage that domain. For 1.99$ you get www.yourname.info and nothing else.( you need dns for your domain to work dns is what tells any internet browser where to go when they try to access www.yourname.abc)